# Issues in Falling Distance Logic Program

Tags: c++, for-loop

The program is supposed to have a user enter the total Time in Seconds and calculate the distance traveled
in meters. The time is supposed to be in increments of 5.Below is what I have so far. I can not figure out how to have the input work with the for loop to also accept input.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

  const double g = 9.8;
  double fallingDistance(double t, double g);
  
int main()
{
  double distance;
  double t;

  cout << "Enter Object's Falling Time in Seconds: " <<endl;
  cin >> t;
  
    if (t<0)
      cout << "ERROR: Cannot input negative time" <<endl;
     
  cout << "Falling Time  Distance Traveled" <<endl;
  cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
  
    for (int i=0; i<=0; t+=5)
    {
       distance = fallingDistance(t, g);
       cout << t << " Seconds    " << distance << " Meters"<<endl;
       cin >> t;
    }

   return 0;
}

double fallingDistance(double t, double g)
{
    return (0.5) * g * pow(t, 2);
}
```

I've tried changing the for loop to `=t(time)` and tried looking into vectors and nested loops, but I am unsure of what to do moving forward. This is early on in my class.

Comment: *The program is supposed to have a user enter the total Time in Seconds and calculate the distance traveled in meters.* -- If that's the case, why is there input inside the loop if the user is supposed to enter the value one time?

Comment: I've tried changing that a few times too.

Comment: I currently have     for (int i=0; i<20; i+=5)
   
    {
       distance = fallingDistance(t, g);
       cout << t << " Seconds\t\t" << distance << " Meters"<<endl;
    }

Comment: I can get out puts but it won't increment up to the entered time by 5 seconds. I just get 4 lines of whatever amount I enter and the output of distance.

Comment: Prefer to use `(x * x)` rather than `pow(x, 2)`.  The multiplication is a lot more efficient and produces accurate results for both integers and floating point.

Comment: BTW, if your program receives negative falling time, it still continues.  Maybe put a `return 1;` or `exit()` in the `if` block, so that the program doesn't run anymore.

Comment: In your `for` loop, where do you change the value of `i`?

Comment: In your `for` loop, why are you incrementing the `t` variable after inputting it?

Comment: for (int i=0; i<50; i+=5) is the current for loop I have written, the math works fine I just cant get the loop to accept input from cin >> t.

Comment: I need to to display starting from 0 secs up to whatever the user would enter and have that increment by 5

Comment: Also thanks on the note about the if statement, that makes sense

Comment: Passing `g` to the function seems pointless, doesn't it? Are you considering different planets and/or moons? Better to not have global declarations, and put it in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Nice that you start to learn C++. Let me try to help you and guide you a little.

I will start with reviewing your source code line by line and add comments regarding my observations and potential refactoring or improvement topics.

```
#include <iostream>     // This is correct
#include <cmath>        // This is correct

using namespace std;    // This is controversal. For people learning the language and for
                        // for small test program this is perfectly fine.
                        // In professional software development you would never use that
                        // because you open the complete std-namespace with many many
                        // names in it. This could lead to clashes and other problems and
                        // should be avoided. Full qualified names using the scope operator ::
                        // Are preferred.But for here: OK

const double g = 9.8;   // Yes, this should be indeed a global constant. And since it is always
                        // Valid, it can also be dfeined outside of any function. But then the single
                        // character name is too short and may collide with other variables. Then
                        // better to use something like: "StandardGravityG0". Then nothing will happen.
                        // Defining it as const is already good, nowadays we would use "constexpr"
                        // in c++, to make it a compile time constant
                        
                        // It is perfectly find to use forward declarations, but the convention in
                        // C++ is to define the functions before there usage. So normally, you would move
                        // The complete function to here. But, as said, perfectly ok.
double fallingDistance(double t, double g);

int main()
{
    double distance;    // All variables should be ALWAYS initialized. You may use the assignement
                        // operator = or, better, use the universal initializer "{}", which can also
                        // detect narrowing conversions happening in the background
    double t;           // Same as above + You should try to avoid single letter variables and use
                        // "speaking" variables instead. The exception are often loop variables

    cout << "Enter Object's Falling Time in Seconds: " << endl;
                        // Using endl is OK, but not necessary with cout. cout and cin are tied together
                        // and the output buffer will automatically be flashed. So you could simple add
                        // a \n at the ned of your string
    cin >> t;           // Very dangerous. You do not check the result of the input operation. You should
                        // always check the state of the stream after any input (and sometimes also output)
                        // function. Imagine somebody would enter "abc" instead of a number.

    if (t < 0)          // Range check is good, but you should only execute the rest of the program in
                        // The 'else' part of the the if-statement
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot input negative time" << endl;    // Regarding endl, see above

    cout << "Falling Time  Distance Traveled" << endl;          // Regarding endl, see above
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;               // Regarding endl, see above
                        // All this 3 couts can be chained or evrything could be put into one string

                        // Here you have your semantic error. Then end condition is worng and the
                        // increment is wrong. I show you the solution later
    for (int i = 0; i <= 0; t += 5)
    {
        distance = fallingDistance(t, g);                       // This is correct
        cout << t << " Seconds    " << distance << " Meters" << endl; // Regarding endl, see above
        cin >> t;       // Unfortunately this is completely wrong
    }
    return 0;           // For main the return statement is optional. You may omit it
}

double fallingDistance(double t, double g)  // G is already a constant and it is not necesary to give it as parameter
{
    return (0.5) * g * pow(t, 2);           // you should not use the pow function here. t*t would be better
}
```

OK, this was the explanation of potential issues and proposals for refactoring.

Now, let's solve the semantic problem. You have a given time and want to show results in increments of 5. So, you can start your loop with a helper variable and increment that by 5. The loop end condition is reached, if your helper is greater than the original given time.

Minimum semantic bug fix added:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
const double StandardGravityG0 = 9.81;

double fallingDistance(double timeInSeconds) {
    return 0.5 * StandardGravityG0 * timeInSeconds * timeInSeconds;
}

int main() {
    double distance{};
    double givenTimeInSeconds{};

    cout << "Enter Object's Falling Time in Seconds:\n";
    cin >> givenTimeInSeconds;

    if (givenTimeInSeconds < 0)
        cout << "\nERROR: Cannot input negative time\n\n";
    else {
        cout << "Falling Time  Distance Traveled\n--------------------------\n";
        for (double currentTime = 0; currentTime <= givenTimeInSeconds; currentTime += 5) {
            distance = fallingDistance(currentTime);
            cout << currentTime << " seconds\t" << distance << " Meters\n";
        }
    }
}
```

---

### .

And if you want to go more in the direction of "more modern C++", then you would probably write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

// Standard gravity on earth
constexpr double StandardGravityG0 = 9.81; 

// Get a positive intger from std::cin and handle errors
double getPositiveDouble() {

    // This will hold the read value
    double result{};

    // Here we will store, if the input is valid or not
    bool inputIsValid{};

    // As long as the input is not valid (which will be true for the first loop run)
    while (not inputIsValid) {

        // Give instruction for the user
        std::cout << "Please enter a positive double: ";

        // Read and check
        if ((std::cin >> result) and (result > 0.0))
            // OK, we got a valid input. We can terminate the loop
            inputIsValid = true;
        else {
            // There was a problem
            // Clear potentially set error bits of the stream
            std::cin.clear();
            // Delete potential existing remaining characters from the input buffer
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            // And, show some error message
            std::cout << "\nError: Invalid Input\n\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Function to calulate the distance in free fall depending on the time
constexpr double fallingDistance(const double timeInSeconds) {
    return 0.5 * StandardGravityG0 * timeInSeconds * timeInSeconds;
}

// Showing the distance for free fall for a gven time in 5s intervalls
int main() {

    // Give instructions for the user
    std::cout << "\nEnter Object's Falling Time in Seconds:\n";
    const double givenTimeInSeconds{ getPositiveDouble() };

    // SHow the header for the output
    std::cout << "\n\nFalling Time            Distance Traveled\n-----------------------------------------\n";

    // Now show distance depending on time in 5s increments
    for (double currentTime = 0; currentTime <= givenTimeInSeconds; currentTime += 5) 

        // And show it on screen
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(6) << currentTime << " seconds\t-->\t" << std::left << std::setw(10)<< fallingDistance(currentTime) << " Meters\n";
}
```

Sorry for the very complex input validation

Comment: Thank you SO much Patricia! This is a huge help. I appreciate your time and thorough  explanations.

Comment: I would argue that the global constant is not a good thing. It is only cared about and used in one function, so that's where it belongs.